# How the report is being generated in rdl to other format like Excel or pdf?

Tags: sql-server, rdl

Is it from the server or in the application?
I am using the below line to Export from rdl.
byte[] bytes = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("EXCEL", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ServerReport part should have been a dead giveaway.

It is being generated from the Report Server.

From [ReportViewer.ServerReport Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.serverreport%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Gets the instance of the Report class that is used when the
>   ProcessingMode for the ReportViewer control is set to [Remote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.processingmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
>
> **Remote**
>
> Specifies remote processing mode against a Reporting Services report
>   server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response. How can i make it from the application instead of generated from Report Server? When I am using visual studio 2008 to create rdl report with toggle, In Excel the hiding property not working properly. When I use visual studio 2010 to create rdl report with toggle its working fine.